Deploying a Telegram bot with a web hook, node-telegram-bot-api
This is my first experience of creating a telegram bot. I picked node-telegram-bot-api, because I simply stumbled on it first and it looked good enough. It's for a hobby project.
While development was almost smooth, with { polling: true }, when it came to deploying I understood that I need to do it via webhook, if I wanted to deploy on Netlify or Vercel.
Is there a guide for doing this? And I mean specifically this package, node-telegram-bot-api. I saw some guides for other languages and packages. And there are some example setups in the package repo. But they all lack the full picture.
